# Add data to a separate app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to make it easy for people to keep their info when upgrading my app to the pro version. How can i send data from the free app to the pro app once they have it on their iPhone? I'm sure i've seen this done before.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is make it all one app, where the pro features can be purchased via in-app purchase. Otherwise, you're going to need some sort of web service to sync data to.

Comment: So it would have to send it up to the web and back to the phone, despite both apps being on the same phone?

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no good way of transferring large amounts of data between apps. You could use potentially a custom URL scheme to transfer small amounts of data (i.e. `myappproversion://sync?username=something&stuff=morestuff`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a custom URL scheme and send the data via such an handler. Have a look at http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Comment: Any idea what the max length is on that?

Comment: Wow, that's even lower than I thought. Wouldn't be able to transfer much, then.

Comment: Probably not as much as I would need. It might sound like a stupid question.. but every object in an app has an ID. Is there a way to get all the subviews and data about that object over to somewhere else simply by using the same ID somewhere else? I take it the answer is no?

Comment: No, you can't. Every application is in it's „jail.“ You cannot access any other applications data. What you CAN do is transfer the profile to a server, save it there and request it in the pro app.